# Format lists in VIM

Tags: list, vim, formatting

I would like to find a way to easy format lists in Vim.
I checked PAR and the default formatter of Vim.

p.e.

```
1. this is my text this is my text this is my text 
2. this is my text this is my text this is my text 
3. this is my text this is my text this is my text 
4. this is my text this is my text this is my text
```

and this

```
- this is my text this is my text this is my text 
- this is my text this is my text this is my text 
- this is my text this is my text this is my text 
- this is my text this is my text this is my text
```

when I select the lines and do a default format to 42 with PAR and VIM these are the results:

---

### NUMBERED LIST

**formatting with par**:
par error:
 (42) <=  (0) +  (50)

**formatting with vim**:

```
1. this is my text this is my text this is
my text 
2. this is my text this is my text this is
my text 
3. this is my text this is my text this is
my text 
4. this is my text this is my text this is
   my text
```

---

### LIST with '-'

**formatting with par**:
4 lines filtered (no change)

**formatting with vim**:

```
- this is my text this is my text this is
  my text 
- this is my text this is my text this is
  my text 
- this is my text this is my text this is
  my text 
- this is my text this is my text this is
  my text
```

---

Vim does a better job formatting lists but it is not correct as well in a numbered list.
Par does have a lot of troubles formatting lists even when I use the prefix ("p") option like this:
'<,'>!par w42p4dh or '<,'>!par w42p3dh

Does anyone know a good way how to format lists without problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `set fo+=n`.  From `:help fo-table`:

```
n       When formatting text, recognize numbered lists.  This actually uses
        the 'formatlistpat' option, thus any kind of list can be used.  The
        indent of the text after the number is used for the next line.  The
        default is to find a number, optionally followed by '.', ':', ')',
        ']' or '}'.  Note that 'autoindent' must be set too.  Doesn't work
        well together with "2".                    

        Example: 
                1. the first item
                   wraps 
                2. the second item
```

Comment: Thank you Randy. I tried to applicate it to my list and added `set fo+=n` and `set formatlistpat="^\d\.\s"` to vim, using the commandline and clicked on `n`. This gives the error: `\<number\> not found`. What did I wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't have to set formatlistpat at all for a simple numbered list.  Just "set fo+=n" then visually select the list and press 'gw' or 'gq' to reformat it.

Comment: thats what I tried first. Doesn't work. All numbers are mixed up.

Comment: What is 'fo' set to?  ":echo &fo".

Comment: :echo &fo = tcqro2n, ok I have seen it. It does not work together with "2"

Comment: Yes, so depending on which you format more often (lists or indented paragraphs) you should either use 'n' or '2'.

Comment: What is `formatprg` set to? It should be empty.